# Switch statement within while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, switch-statement, infinite-loop

There are several postings concerning switch statements within while loops, except for the fact that none of them are done in C, at least from what I've seen. C++ can create boolean expressions, which I'm aware of, but not in C. I have a while loop that contains a switch control. However, when I write break statements within my switch, it goes back to the beginning of the loop and makes my program run forever. Ignore the functions I use, for they work for sure. I just need some clarification on my handling of the nesting. Thanks!

```
Here is my main.c:

while(1)
{
    printf("0) Exit\n1) List Tasks\n2) Add Task\n");                                            
    printf("3)Delete Task\n4) Add Task From File\n");                                           
    printf("What would you like to do?\n");
    fgets(buf1, 50, stdin);                                                                     
    p = atoi(buf1);
    switch(p)
    {
          case 0: 
            break;
          case 1: 
            printTaskList(pTaskList);
            break;
          case 2:
            printf("Enter task name: ");
            fgets(buf2,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter task priority: ");
            fgets(buf3,100,stdin);
            printf("Enter task start date: ");
            fgets(buf4,50,stdin);
            pTask = makeTask(buf2,buf4,buf3);
            addTaskToEnd(pTaskList,pTask);
            break;
          case 3:
            printTaskList(pTaskList);
            printf("What task would you like to delete? ");
            fgets(buf6,50,stdin);
            taskNum = atoi(buf6);
            removeTask(pTaskList,taskNum);
            break;
          case 4:
            printf("Enter the filename ");
            fgets(buf7,50,stdin);
            break;
          default:
            printf("ERROR: %d: Incorrect menu option\n", p);
     }
}
```

Comment: Your break statement serves to skip the rest of the switch clauses, which means you dump out at the line after the switch. A common solution to breaking all the way out of a nested scope is to move the code into a function and use return instead of break.

Comment: identify the points you want to break OUT of the while loop within your switch body, set a flag indicating this, and make the `while(expression)` evaluate the flag for the break-state (i.e. `while(true)` becomes `while(stay_in_while)`, and have `stay_in_while` cleared by the switch code you want to break.

Comment: You are mistaken, C has Boolean expressions and data type. It has a builtin type `_Bool` and if you include `<stdbool.h>` there are also `bool`, `false`, and `true`.

Comment: Why would you edit out your question? You should leave it as it was, so that other people can use the answers you got.

Comment: Downvoted it as he edited it and removed it for others. Need a mod to roll it back maybe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`break;` will exit out of the nearest enclosing `switch` or loop. To jump two levels, you'll have to use the dreaded `goto`, or reorganize so a `return` will accomplish the desired semantics.

```
while(1) {
    switch(x) {
    case 0: goto EndWhile;
    }
}
EndWhile: ;
```

Or

```
void loop() {
    while(1) {
        switch(x) {
        case 0: return;
        }
    }
}
//...
loop();
//...
```

You can totally use a *Boolean expression* in C. Just use an `int`.

```
int quit = 0;
while(!quit) {
    switch(x) {
    case 0: quit = 1; break;
    }
}
```

C also has a boolean data type, if you really want it.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool quit = false;
while(!quit) {
    switch(x) {
    case 0: quit = true; break;
    }
}
```

And one more option, for the *totally insane.*

```
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf jbuf;
if (!setjmp(jbuf))
    while(1) {
        switch(x) {
        case 0: longjmp(jbuf, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You made it really clear! Thank you so much! Your code fixed my infinite loop error, as well as all of you guys. I realized I had to flag where I wanted to exit the while loop, so I just changed "quit" to become the negation of "quit."

Comment: Using `int` as boolean works, and is very common, but I definitely prefer the stdbool style. `while`, `if`, and so on all take a boolean expression, and it does not feel logically correct to give them a number instead. `quit` is not a number, it is a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can have boolean expressions in C too. The C standard from 1999 has a **stdbool.h** header and a data type **bool**. In older C dialects, such as the one in Visual Studio 2012 (!), there is no boolean data type, so you need to use plain ints instead:

```
int keep_looping = 1;
while (keep_looping) {
    ....
    if (....)
        keep_looping = 0;
}
```

Comment: @modifiable lvalue: There certainly is, in the standard. And Visual Studio 2012 _still_ doesn't have it. But you are right, I shouldn't have said that there is no boolean type. Let's hope for his sake that he's not stuck with Microsoft.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 doesn't have a C compiler. In the interest of countering any "but there's a 'compile as C code' option" arguments: It isn't uncommon for perfectly valid C code that's been written in the last decade to fail to compile using VS. If it can't compile C code, then it's not a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You never exit the loop. The break will just break your switch. You should replace

```
while(1)
```

with something else that implies that the while-loop should be exited

Answer (score 0):

Your break only leaves the switch statement, then continues on in the

```
while(1)
```

loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

> C++ can create boolean expressions, which I'm aware of, but not in C.

Oh? So what is `0 == 0`, if not a boolean expression? If you're referring to a variable of the type `bool`, make sure you `#include <stdbool.h>`.

> However, when I write break statements within my switch, it goes back
>   to the beginning of the loop and makes my program run forever. Ignore
>   the functions I use, for they work for sure. I just need some
>   clarification on my handling of the nesting. Thanks!

No. It doesn't go back to the beginning of the loop. Execution continues from the end of the switch statement (immediately after the `switch`es closing brace, `}`). In your circumstance, this is functionally identical to *going back to the beginning of the loop*.

There are a few of options available to you. Others are suggesting using a sole variable to control your loop. This would be a good idea, but they're suggesting using *new* variables, despite the fact that the variable already exists in your logic. If you want to solve your problem this way, consider:

```
do {
    /* ... */
} while (p != 0);
```

Alternatively, `return` from main when you want to exit, or call `exit(0);` from other functions. This isn't all that helpful if you want to run extra cleanup/output code.

In this scenario, the `switch` control structure isn't really any better than a chain of `if`/`else if`/`else` branches. If you were to use the `if`/`else if`/`else` branches, you'd be able to `break;` out of the loop more easily. I'd use a `switch` control structure when I want execution to flow through into other cases.

As another option, you could use a `goto` expression to break out of the loop to a label outside of main. This would be best when there are multiple possible exit points from the loop, such as handling and cleanup following allocation errors.

Answer (score 0):

use **exit(0);**

wherever you want to exit.

`In this partcular case you have to put the condition in the while loop parameter`

other ways to come out from the while loop might be to use:
`return` statement. But this will also exit the current function.

Appropriate solution might be to use `goto label;` inside the switch and then use `label: statement;` outside the while loop.

Eg:

```
while(1){
  switch(x){

   case 0:goto label;

   default:break;
   }
}
label:
printf("out of while loop");
```

Comment: should be in comments. This is very tiny answer IMO.

Comment: Doesn't this only work if he wants to completely exit the entire program?  Wouldn't `return 0` be more appropriate, though most likely still incorrect?

Comment: 'return' exits from the function while 'exit' exits from the whole program.